# Angular 5 - Manage right the server request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I am read that it's recommend to make the server requests via services(and not via components) so that the function's request, will can be a reusable(by another components). of curse that in the end, we need the server response in the component.

My question is what is best practice to make the call from the component to the service for get the data. i asking because the http request, will be action by Observable, mean that it's asynchronous action.

so, if i will do something like this:

```
//data.component.ts
  const data = this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer();

//httpService.service.ts
  getDataFromTheServer(){
       return this.http.post(url).map(
         res=>res.json())
       }
```

the data never get in to the component's variable.

My solution for this problem is to use in another "Subject". something like this:

```
 //data.component.ts     

 this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer()
 this.httpService.getData.subscribe(res => {
    const data = res;
}

//httpService.service.ts

   public getData = new Subject();

  getDataFromTheServer(){
       return this.http.post(url).map(
         res=> this.getData.next(res.json()))
       }
```

like this it's will fork fine. but am not sure if this is the best practice for this issue.

anybody have another idea? thanks a lot!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to all respondents. i got that i can doing this in my component:

```
this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer().subscribe...
```

but i wonder if i can cleaning my components more, and make do with only this:

```
const data = this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer()
```

or if there is another way to cleaning the components? or maybe i did not understand the recommendation "make the server requests via services" enough? 
i would be happy to explain more clearly.

Comment: I think you are missing the .subscribe() in the data.component.ts; this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer().subscribe((data) => {...});

Comment: This is all covered in great detail in [the docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ofc your first solution won't work. Its because "this.http.post" method is not returning request data, but observable object. So what you need to do, is subscribe to your object :)

```
//data.component.ts
const data = this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer();
data.subscribe(res => console.log(res)); // or just bind res to any other variable

//httpService.service.ts
  getDataFromTheServer(){
     return this.http.post(url).map(
       res=>res.json())
     }
```

This solution also gives you ability to unsubscribe from your Observale

```
ngOnDestroy() {
  this.data.unsubscribe();
}
```

And at the very end, you don't really need to bind your service method to any variable. You can simply do this:

```
//data.component.ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer()
  .subscribe(res => myVariable = res) // binding response from server to variable
}

//httpService.service.ts
  getDataFromTheServer(){
     return this.http.post(url)
     .map(res=>res.json())
   }
```

// Answer to edit

In theory you can, however i wont recommend it. Just use async pipe if you want to keep your component clear

Do this like this:

// component.html

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of (items | async)">
</ul>
// or if its not an array
<h1>{{ item | async }}</h1>
```

// component.ts

```
public items;

ngOnInit() {
  this.items = this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer();
}
```

// service.ts

```
getDataFromTheServer(){
   return this.http.post(url).pipe(map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: thanks you for your quick response. please see my edit

Comment: Very interesting. Why dont you recommend it?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
//data.component.ts
this.httpService.getDataFromTheServer().subscribe((data) => {
   //assign your data here
});

//httpService.service.ts
getDataFromTheServer(){
   return this.http.post(url);
}
```

as `this.http.post` is returning an `Observable<any>` and you need to subscribe to it.

Comment: thanks you for your quick response. please see my edit